# Which compiler is used when building solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jit

I was reading up on JIT and AOT compiler and found that CLR in .NET uses JIT compilation. But I also read that the build process in Visual Studio includes compilation and linking, among other things.

I assume JIT compilation happens when the request hits IIS. What kind of compilation happens during the build phase in Visual Studio?

Comment: From source code to IL opcodes. JIT compiles IL to CPU commands at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIT is a "Just-In-Time" compiler which is used to compile IL to the machine commands. Compiler compiles your code to the IL language.

Compiler used to compile solution is MSBuild/Roslyn. There are other compilers used to compile e.g. web pages like ASP.NET Compilation Tool.

Comment: MSBuild builds the entire solution. Right? Which includes compiling, linking, running tests, etc. The compiler it uses is `csc.exe`. Right?